# jquery: read inside each div, span and input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, clone

I'm creating a project in ASP.NET MVC and jQuery. When a user click on `addSentence` button, I want to duplicate a `div` called `copythis` with all events and insert it in another div called `myform`.

in `copythis` I have two div: in the first there is a `span` called `sentence` where I insert the text in the `input` in the second the user can add more then one field with different text.

When the user clicks the button called `save` I want to read all `copythis` in `myform` and create a structure to send to a webapi.
I have a problem is the javascript because I can read properly each div.

```js
        $("#addSentence").on("click", function (event) {
            if ($("#inputSentence").val() == "")
                alert("Sentence must have a value");
            else {
                event.preventDefault();
                var theContainer = $("#copythis");
                if (theContainer != null) {
                    var clonedSection = $(theContainer).clone(true);
                    if (clonedSection != null) {
                        $(clonedSection).find("#sentence")
                                        .text($("#inputSentence").val());
                        $(clonedSection).appendTo("#myform");
                    }
                }
            }
    });

    $("#save").on("click", function (event) {
        $("#myform #copythis").children().each(function (index, element) {
            var elm = $(this);
            var sentence = elm.find('.row span#sentence').val();
            if (sentence != '') {
                console.log('Sentence: ' + sentence);
                $("input").children().each(function (m, l) {
                    var txt = $(this).val();
                    if (txt != '') {
                        console.log('Example: ' + txt);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

    function makeRepeater(sectionsSelector, addClass, removeClass, AYSMsg) {
        $(sectionsSelector + " " + addClass + "," + sectionsSelector + 
          " " + removeClass).on("click", function (event) {
            // Avoiding the link to do the default behavior.
            event.preventDefault();

            // Get the container to be removed/cloned
            var theContainer = $(this).parents(sectionsSelector);
            if ($(this).is(addClass)) {

                // Cloning the container with events
                var clonedSection = $(theContainer).clone(true);

                // And appending it just after the current container
                $(clonedSection).insertAfter(theContainer);
            } else {
                // If the user confirm the "Are You Sure" message
                // we can remove the current container
                if (confirm(AYSMsg)) {

                    // Making fade out, hide and remove element a sequence
                    // to provide a nice UX when removing element.
                    $(theContainer).fadeOut('normal',
                        function () {
                            $(this).hide('fast',
                                function () { $(this).remove(); }
                            );
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        });
    }

    makeRepeater(
        '.my-repeated-section-form',   /* The container selector */
        '.addform',                   /* The add action selector */
        '.removeform',                /* The remove action selector */
        'Are you sure you want to remove this section?' /* The AYS message. */
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="inputSentence" type="text" 
                       class="form-control" placeholder="Sentence...">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" 
                            type="button" id="addSentence">Add</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div style="display: inline;">
            <div class="group-of-repeated-sections" style="display: none;">
                <div class="my-repeated-section">
                    <div id="copythis">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <span id="sentence"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <span>
                                    <a href="#" class="add"> + </a>
                                    <a href="#" class="remove"> - </a>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="my-repeated-section-form">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <input type="text" />
                                    <span>
                                        <a href="#" class="addform"> + </a>
                                        <a href="#" class="removeform"> - </a>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="height:25px;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="myform"></div>
<button id="save">Save</button>
```

Comment: Looks mostly functional. Which piece is the problem?

Comment: from when I click the button `$("#myform #copythis")`. I want to read first `sentence` and the all `input` in the same `div` but different `row`